# How to run two enumerateNodes together in a function

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to run 2 enumerateChildNodes codes at the same time within a function. At the moment, both enumerate codes work!

```
func change() {

scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*one*") {
(node, stop) in
node.name = "two"
}

scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*two*") {
(node, stop) in
 node.name = "one"
}
}
```

However, because the first enumerate changes the node.name to "two" this will trigger the second enumerate and it will change the node.name back to "one".

How do I avoid this?

I want the function to work as following:

nodes currently with name "two", change to "one"

nodes currently with name "one", change to "two"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a way to run them concurrently and remember each states and only change the name when it applies
If they were all an object of a certain sub class you could put a property in the class and check for that property

```
func change() {

    scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*one*") { (node, stop) in
        if node is SomeInGameSubClass {
            node.isSwapped = true
            node.name = "two"
        }
    }

    scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*two*") { (node, stop) in
        if node is SomeInGameSubClass {
            if !node.isSwapped {
                node.name = "one"
            }
            else {
                node.isSwapped = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or just convert the first set to an arbitrary name, convert the second set and then go back and convert the first set again

```
func change() {

    scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*one*") { (node, stop) in
        node.name = "temp"
    }

    scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*two*") { (node, stop) in
        node.name = "one"
    }

    scene?.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*temp*") { (node, stop) in
        node.name = "two"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ron! I ended up using the 2nd method. I checked it and it seems fast enough with no bugs. Awesome :D

Comment: Cheers! Likewise.